# Having trouble working with data from component to component with Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web, components

The main issue has something to do with the fact that I'm trying to have one component interact with another. I have a list of songs and the idea is that when one song is clicked it calls a function in the "now-playing-bar" component.

Just hitting the play/Pause button calls the `playPause` function and that works great. The issue comes from when you click a song on the "playlist" component and it calls the function `playSong` in the "now-playing-bar" component. The function itself seems to work fine, the song starts to play and the data values seem to be assigned. However two errors occur.

Error 1: 
The html does not update to show the new title and artist.

Error 2: 
When clicking play/pause to pause a song played from the "playlist" component, `playPause` function correctly outputs `this` with all it's correct data fields, but outputs `undefined` for `this.playing`

*Code is abbreviated for easier reading*

**now-playing-bar.component.html**

```
<div class="song">{{currentSong.title}}</div>
<div class="artist">{{currentSong.artist}}</div>
```

**now-playing-bar.component.ts**

```
export class NowPlayingBarComponent implements OnInit {
    isActive: boolean;
    progress: number = 10;
    playing: boolean;
    currentSong: Song = {
        "id": null,
        "title": "",
        "artist": "",
        "length": "",
        "fileName": ""
    };
    song: any;
    songs: Song[] = [];

    constructor(private songService : SongsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.songService.fetchData()
            .subscribe(d => this.songs = d as Song[]);
    }

    playPause() {
        console.log('Play Pause this:');
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.playing);
        if (this.playing) {
            console.log('Its playing');
            this.playing = false;
            this.song.pause();
        }
        else {
            if (!this.song) {
                this.song = new Howl({
                    src: ['assets/music/' + this.songs[0].fileName]
                });
            }
            this.currentSong = this.songs[0];
            this.playing = true;
            this.song.play();
        }
    }

    playSong(id: number) {
        let that = this;
        this.songService.fetchData()
            .subscribe(function(d) {
                if (that.playing) {
                    that.song.stop();
                    that.song.unload();
                }
                that.song = new Howl({
                    src: ['assets/music/' + d[id].fileName]
                });
                console.log(that.song)
                console.log(that)
                that.currentSong = d[id];
                that.playing = true;
                that.song.play();
            });
    }
}
```

**playlist.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Song from "../models/Song"
import { SongsService } from "../songs.service";
import { NowPlayingBarComponent } from "../now-playing-bar/now-playing-bar.component"

export class PlaylistComponent implements OnInit {
    songs: Song[] = [];

    constructor(private songService : SongsService, private NP : NowPlayingBarComponent) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.songService.fetchData()
            .subscribe(d => this.songs = d as Song[]);
    }

    songClicked(id) {
        this.NP.playSong(id)
    }
}
```

I'm happy to upload the full code if that would help, just didn't want to make it a cluttered mess. I've spent hours researching trying to figure this out but I just can't seem to get it. My best guess is the way that the "playlist" component is interacting with the "now-playing-bar" is incorrect.

Comment: Injecting one component into another component is not a good practice and advocated at all. You should rather use Input/Output to communicate between parent/child component. In this case `NowPlayingBarComponent` should accept the `songId` via an input and the act on it every time it changes.

Comment: I'll give that a shot thanks

Comment: Maybe I just don't get it but I didn't have luck with the input. I tried creating a music service and moved the functions into there. So now the music service has data for song, songs[], playing, etc and functions like init() and playpause(). Say issue though. If I call musicservice.init() and then musicservice.playpause(), playpause doesn't see any changes in the variables that init() made to them. Do these also need input added to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have implemented a working example @ https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-to-component.

It uses two components `Playlist` and `NowPlayingNavbar` based on your example. I've also added a simulated `SongService` to emulated `fetchData` method.

> Note: Avoid calling services from nested child components.

Have a look at Presentation vs Container components pattern in UI development.